# origen_testers ATP flow loop method use case?

Tags: origen-sdk

What is the use case for the [origen_testers ATP flow 'loop' method](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/blob/master/lib/origen_testers/atp/flow.rb#L579)?  Is this meant to be something users call in their flow file or is something under the hood?  Does this method specifically generate something specific for the V93K SMT7 platform?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that the users call in their flow file.

I haven't used it personally, but from [these spec tests](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/blob/master/spec/atp/loop_spec.rb#L30), it looks like you would do something like:

```
loop from: 0, to: 5, step: 1, var: "vol" do
  test :test_loop1
end
```

The `var` value is optional, in that case it will presumably generate a variable name.

Being part of the flow, this API can be called for any tester, however I suspect that only the V93K generator actually will actuall do something with it currently.

Comment: I tested this out in the flow_control.rb example file and did not see any change in the V93K generated flow file, even though the ATP did show a loop node.  I believe an enhancement is required to use this ATP flow API.